# jquery hide/show based on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, show-hide

So I was given a web template that uses a jquery library called sticky, and it "sticks" the navigation (starts at the bottom and moves up) at the top of the page, as you scroll.

I want to be able to plop a logo onto the navigation once it hits its resting place (post scroll). Similar to this website - http://99u.com/.  Once you scroll past the image header, the logo fade's in to the nav bar and then stays on the page. Anyhow, here is the excerpt of the jquery code:

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('nav').sticky({ topSpacing:0, className: 'sticky', wrapperClassName: 'my-wrapper' });
  });
</script>
```

And here is the excerpt of the html:

```
<div with image slideshow></div>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="thirteen columns">
      <ul id="nav" class="links">
        <li id="sticker"><img src="[image i want to display after scroll]" /></li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contests</li>
        <li>etc.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div's and the rest of the page's content></div>
```

This whole template is responsive. Any help would be appreciated, or if someone can point me in the right direction.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the position property of the menu and when it changes, hide/show the image via adding/removing a class:

CSS:

```css
#sticker.hidden { width:0; height:0; border:0; padding:0; margin:0; }
#sticker.hidden * { display:none; }
```

Javascript:

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    $('nav').sticky({
        topSpacing: 0,
        className: 'sticky',
        wrapperClassName: 'my-wrapper'
    });
    var elem = $('#sticker');
    var nav = $('nav');
    var pos = nav.css('position');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (nav.css('position')!=pos) { // if changed
            if (pos=='fixed') {
                elem.addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                elem.removeClass('hidden');
            }
            pos = nav.css('position');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caBF4/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) and [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

This is untested but it would look something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($("#nav").offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop)
    $("#nav").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px", "left":"0px"});
  else
    $("#nav").css({"position":"relative"});
});
```

Basically, as the user scrolls, check the windows scroll position and if it passes the top of the nav, switch the nav over to fixed positioning. In my code above, the check on the way back may need a little tweaking but when they scroll to a position less than the height of the nav, put the nav back to relative positioning.

Also instead of switching to position fixed you could show/hide a totally separate nav, might actually make life easier.

-Ken

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions.  They both helped!  Here is what i ended up doing:

```
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#sticker').css({'display':'none'});
    $('nav').sticky({ topSpacing:0, className: 'sticky', wrapperClassName: 'my-wrapper' });
    $(this).scroll(function() {
      if($('nav').offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('#sticker').fadeIn('fast');
      } else {
        $('#sticker').css({'display':'none'});
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```